# UItableview reload methode is calling before another methode

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to fill UItableview from server data. I use below code but tableview is loading first and then methose.

```
[self GetReaction:(@"12")];   // This method fetch the data from server.

[_tblLines reloadData];    //Reload Ui Table view
```

When i print message using NSLOG then  [_tblLines reloadData];  first and then  [self GetReaction:(@"12")];

```
2013-06-18 17:30:51.970 Penguin[2230:c07] Counter    //Table view
2013-06-18 17:30:51.974 Penguin[2230:c07] Counter
2013-06-18 17:30:51.978 Penguin[2230:c07] Counter
2013-06-18 17:30:51.988 Penguin[2230:c07] Counter
2013-06-18 17:30:52.794 Penguin[2230:c07] Your Array elements are = Mind Blowing :)//methode
2013-06-18 17:30:52.795 Penguin[2230:c07] Your Array elements are = Thanks Superb :)
2013-06-18 17:30:52.822 Penguin[2230:c07] Your Array elements are = Mind Blowing :)
2013-06-18 17:30:52.822 Penguin[2230:c07] Your Array elements are = Thanks Superb :)
```

Anybody tell me why [_tblLines reloadData] method is calling first actually i calling it after `[self GetReaction:(@"12")]` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because fetching from data will take some time. 
In mean time it will continue to execute code.
You should reload table when u receive the data from the server.

Comment: Hi, Thanks lot for your reply. So, How can i call [_tblLines reloadData]; after getting data?

Comment: that depends on how u coded it. Can u add ur code to call server for asking these data?

Comment: Hi I think you are right. My array is multidimensional (2d array). can you please tell me how can i assign 2d array to tableview cell.

I know how to assign single dimension
cell.nameLabel.text =[ReactionDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Can you please help me for 2d array.

Comment: @Shailesh : this is off topic. If you solved your problem, accept BSThakrar's answer, and open a new question.

Comment: My dear friend yes BSThakrar's solve my problem but i really appreciate if you help me to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: ask a new question if your problem of multidimensional array isn't solved yet.